# Как временно отключить событие wheel?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

пишу код для постраничного скроллинга и столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть обработчик события для мышки который показывает в какую сторону крутили колесико.
И проблема в том, что мне нужно добавить какую то задержку до следующего скролла.

```js
document.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
      e.deltaY;
            if (e.deltaY < 0) {
               scrollDirection = 'up';

            }
            if (e.deltaY > 0) {
                scrollDirection = 'down';
            }
            scrollPage(scrollDirection);
}
```

Что бы допустим, и 1 тик колесика или 3 тика, срабатывало как один.
Так как при 3 тиках, скроллит сразу на 3 страницы
Я пробовал записывать в отдельную функцию и удалять событие, потому через setTimout добавлять его снова, но не работает
Может кто сталкивался и может подсказать?
Желательно без jQuery, спасибо

Comment: в решении в дубликате jquery не используется

Comment: да, увидел, спасибо. Это помогло
Но оно просто откладывает событие на какой то таймер
В примере 250, попробовал у себя для этого же значения и 400, 600. Да, за это время больше чем одно событие не считывает, но так же и выполняет его через это время. Как бы выполнить сразу но задержку на считывание оставить?

Comment: Там есть параметр `immediate` - если его передаешь `true` первый вызов без задержки происходит

Comment: так же можешь поискать реализацию `throttle` а не `debounce`

Comment: Заработало, спасибо огромное )
Обязательно почитаю об этом)